Remove a entry from hibernate collection without fetching entire collection
Using Hibernate, I have bi-directional association between person/address. Person entity can have too many addresses and I want to add and remove to address collection without loading entire collection.
Below is a example depicting my case, in my real case, number of address entities are huge that i want to avoid loading all of them when doing add/remove.
Java class:
public class Person
{
   private UUID id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    public Person addAddress(Address address) {
        addresses.add(address);
        address.setPerson(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Person removeAddress(Address address) {
        // though i want to remove one specific address entity association,
        // it loads all addresses which is a lot impacting perf
        addresses.remove(address);
        address.setPerson(null);
        return this;
    }
}

public class Address {

    @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotNull
    private Person person;

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person; ...
    }

}

When i want to dissassociate a address from Person entity, i call person.removeAddress(address) which loads all the addresses of this person. In my case there are 100s of them and i want to avoid loading all of them into memory.
Once my modifications are done on entity, i call personRepository.flush() and don't do any manual HQL query.
Are there any solutions to avoid loading all addresses of this person, when i only want to remove one given address association?

public class Person
{
   private UUID id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();

    public Person addAddress(Address address) {
        if (Hibernate.isInitialized(addresses)) {
           addresses.add(address);
        }
        address.setPerson(this);
        return this;
    }

    public Person removeAddress(Address address) {
        if (Hibernate.isInitialized(addresses)) {
           addresses.remove(address);
        }
        address.setPerson(null);
        return this;
    }
}

In above add/remove methods, i use Hibernate.isInitialized method to check if the collection is already loaded in hibernate cache, only then I modify the collection, otherwise, I update the other side of relationship i.e Address->Person and that works.
Updating other side of relationship is enough and updating collection isn't needed since Address is the owner side of the relationship here.

By including the mappedBy attribute in the Person class, we mark it as the inverse side. At the same time, we also annotate the Address.person field with @ManyToOne, making Address the owning side.

From: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many
Based on this, Hibernate knows that Address's reference is more important and will save Address's reference to the database.
Note: If addresses collection is initialized, it should be updated with correct references. Otherwise, it can lead to issues like mapping stale references.
